# Connecting VS Code to existing Git repository

Tags: git

My client has a pre-existing git repository.
I downloaded a zip file of the typescript angular project to my local machine and modified the code in VS Code.
Now I need to upload and commit my changes to the git repository.
I am following the instructions here, [CheatSheet - Setup Github on Visual Studio Code](http://www.notyourdadsit.com/blog/2018/4/3/cheatsheet-setup-github-on-visual-studio-code)
but I am getting the message

> fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directoies)

How do I connect VS Code to git to commit my changes?

Comment: starting with just a zip copy of the repo will **never** work. Clone the repo in a separate directory, copy over the modified files and commit and push

Comment: @rioV8 Why will it never work? If the zip contains the .git folder it should be fine. It sounds like that is missing however.

Comment: @evolutionxbox: a commit contains a reference to the parent commit. Without the repository you don't have the commit history

Comment: @rioV8 exactly why I think the git folder is missing. The OP has kinda confused things because the error is both “not a repo” and “repo already exists”.

Comment: if you download the zip from github you do **not** get the `.git` folder and you need this to make commits

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a repository with the same folder name.

```
git init
```

Be aware of the naming convention of git.

Comment: You need to clone it.

Comment: @CMX it can’t both not be a repo and be one. Please update your question with the commands you have used and their output.

Comment: Is it a public repository?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you describe

- If you have  a pre-existing git repository. you can coppy project into. Then you commit and push code project.
- Else you can use `git init`

Comment: how would I copy the project into?

Comment: you coppy projet into where you use `git clone  <url>`

Comment: sorry, I don't understand

Comment: uhm.. you can read https://help.github.com/en/articles/cloning-a-repository

Comment: this looks helpful. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It will work... but you need to do some additional work.

First, find out from what revision of git you started working from. Make a clone of the git repository (normal flow) into your computer. Then `git checkout` *that exact revision* that you started working from... and I mean **revision** not branch. If it was from master.... but it's not the current tip of master, it wont work if you checkout the branch, you need the *exact* revision. Create a branch at that point for your feature:

```
git checkout -b my-branch
```

Now delete *all* files in the project and replace it with the files as you have them in your VS project..... there should be no changes *other than the changes you made*... no deleted files.... no additional files.... no changes *except your changes* (if you added files, well.. those will have to be added.... if you deleted files... well, they will have to be deleted as well). Then commit, push as needed and that's it. Find the way to import this into VS and you should be fine.